# Multiple Authentication

Tags: gmail, hotmail, yahoo-mail

I am creating a web-page/website that integrates all my accounts into one spectrum, as in, from this page I want to use this page to log into my mail box online or any other site that requires authentication. All i want is a central login panel. enter my unname&passwd and get redirected to my mail. Is that an impossible question to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **completely** depends on the individual service. You'll have to investigate each service  to see if they even allow you to authenticate against their servers remotely. In the event that they do allow it, it's still up to the service whether or not you'll be able to retrieve any kind of information from them after logging in.

Banks in particular are very unlikely to give you any way to interface with them and the ones that do will likely require a monthly access fee.

Comment: in the case with the bank i might just put up the link and a logo

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want to consider using [OpenId](http://openid.net/), which is a standard, fairly widely adopted form of single sign-on. Used by this very site, in fact, and supported by at least two of the three companies you mentioned: yahoo and google. Hotmail does not currently support it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language), an XML-based standard for exchanging authentication and authorization data between security domains, that is, between an identity provider (a producer of assertions) and a service provider (a consumer of assertions). SAML is a product of the OASIS Security Services Technical Committee.

With SAML, you can communicate between the major single sign on (SS0) technologies like CAS, OpenID, Shibboleth, AD/LDAP...